# Can two positive monotonically increasing functions cross more than once?

Tags: functions

Given two positive monotone increasing functions $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ over positive integers, such that $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are rounded to their nearest higher integer after calculation. Lets denote it by $Rnd(f(a))$ or $Rnd(g(a))$.

Can these two functions cross each other more than once?
By crossing we mean:

1. $Rnd(f(a))<Rnd(g(a))$
2. $Rnd(f(a+1))>Rnd(g(a+1))$

Is there an upper bound on how many times these functions can cross? This is in regards to running time of algorithms.

Edit: Just to reiterate, functions are positive, take integer input, give integer output (ceil criteria) and are same over all integers (no if else etc.). P.S. Think running time of algorithms.

Comment: I don't understand the ceiling part.  Aren't you just saying that $f,g$ are functions from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't have a hard time constructing examples of what you want, even with infinitely many crossings.

Comment: take integer input and output the nearest higher integer not a real number after calculation

Comment: I don't understand.  Since $f(n)$ is equal to a ceiling, then it is an integer itself.  So, that's all you are saying.  It's different, I think, if you say that $f$ is the "rounding" of an increasing function.  A strictly increasing function could "round" to a constant, say.  Anyway, what you wrote is not at all clear.

Comment: @lulu updated. is it clearer ?

Comment: I still think that you just mean to consider integer valued functions.  The rounding part seems irrelevant.   In any case, you can construct integer valued functions that cross infinitely often, as the posted solutions discuss.  And the "running time" digression is incomplete.  If you have a restriction on the running time, you should specify it clearly.  But surely something like $f(n)=10n$, $g(n)=10n+(-1)^n$ is as efficient as one could ask for, no?

Comment: There are algorithms that have a running time of $f(n)=n.log(n)$, n is the number of bits in input. The input will be number of bits i.e. an integer, the output will be a real number, hence the rounding etc.

Comment: I have updated my Answer with a Discussion regarding running time of algorithms which have Crossings [[ I am not sure what Exactly you are looking for !! ]]

Answer (score 1):

You can consider these 2 functions :

- $f(a) = 5 \times a$
- $g(a) =5 \times a+1$ when a is even , $g(a) =5 \times a-1$ when a is odd

Comment: its regarding running time of algorithms. so the if/else kind won't work.

Comment: @xyz You did not specify no if/else.

Comment: I thought running time of algorithms made it clearer. The running time is a function calculated over number of bits in input, and is a single function.

Comment: @xyz An if-else does not mean that this isn’t a single function.  This is a function, the formula has an if-else to make it easier to understand it’s structure.  In fact, this could even be the runtime of an algorithm - there are lots of algorithms which behave slightly differently on odd and even inputs.

Comment: @MichaelBurr can you please provide an example of an algo that behaves like this (in their optimal running time. the input being the number of bits (n))?

Comment: @xyz A complete algorithm should be asked as a different question (and likely on a different stack).  For a simple example of this type of behavior, think of merge sort - the recursion tree isn't perfectly balanced unless the number of inputs is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very Intuitive way to look at this :

Let there be 2 runners who are always advancing. Then the Distances [ D(R1) & D(R2) ] travelled from the Starting Point are monotonically increasing functions.

We can take rounding [ Round(D(R1)) & Round(D(R2)) ] to get Integer value functions.

Initially , let R1 zoom fast , with R2 trailing.

A while later , let R1 slow down (yet not go back) while R2 zooms fast to over-take R1.

A while later , let R2 slow down (yet not go back) while R1 zooms fast to over-take R2.

A while later , let R1 slow down (yet not go back) while R2 zooms fast to over-take R1.

A while later , let R2 slow down (yet not go back) while R1 zooms fast to over-take R2.

....
....

Every time R1 over-takes R2 ( or R2 over-takes R1 ) , the Distances are Equal , that is , we get a Crossing of the functions.

We can have unlimited Crossings , if there is alternation of the leading runner.
We can have limited Crossings , if eventually R1 ( or R2 ) remains leading.

We can get Intuition through this View Point.

OP wants the Case where the functions are the Run time of algorithms :

Let the 2 runners pick up tasks on the way & Execute that tasks & then move forward.
Essentially , we are Executing some algorithms.

Concretely : Eg : let there be numbers on the race track.
The runners have to Evaluate the largest number on a Paper Book.
Hence Starting with MAX = 0 , when-ever a new number X is on the race track , the runners compare with Existing number & update MAX if X is larger.
At the Completion of the race , MAX will be the largest number in the race track.

Due to Access Issues or road conditions or tiredness , time to write on the Paper Book or Etc , the runners are either very fast or very slow alternatively.

We have the Same Case , with Crossings when-ever the leading runner changes alternatively ....

Comment: I understood the concept. sincerely thank you. But the algo example is not fine. When i say algo I mean a CS/mathematical algorithm in which there is an input, the running time is calculated on the number of bits in input and is optimal. so this example might not be rigorous with all due respect.

Comment: Actually , it is the Same in algorithms too. Think that the race track is the HardDisk & every Sector has some Data which must be Processed (to evaluate MAX or to get a Hash or to Encrypt) & think that the runners are Processes. The Processes can try to read the Sectors , get stuck in Paging or thrashing or Busy Signal or high CPU load or ETC. When Process1 get Data , it will zoom on, while Process2 will be stuck. When Process2 get Data , it will zoom on, while Process1 will be stuck. There will be a race with alternating leader. We can make the functions for this which will have Crossings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see for example,
$$x\mapsto \begin{cases}x\\x+\sin x\end{cases}$$
in WolframAlpha:

[image: A graph of x and (x plus sine of x)]

Link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%3B+x+%2B+sin%28x%29+in+%28-10%3B10%29

Comment: won't work since $x+sin(x)$ rounded to nearest higher integer would result in $x$ or $x+1$. so there is no crossing in this case. am i correct?

Comment: It won't? Just take $x = \text{[your integer input]}/100$ and similarly $\text{[your integer output]} = Rnd( y\times 100)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it surely can.

[image: Geogebra]

For $x > -0.5$, both functions meet your criterias and cross two times.

That's because you didn't imply that their derivate must be monotical too:

[image: Geogebra (2)]

You see that the blue function catches up the green one for $x > 0$ because its derivatives cross each other.

**Update:**

Here is an Octave graph for integers and ceiled values:

[image: Octave]

Here is the code, with the functions used:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

f = @(x) ceil(x.^2 + x + 0.1);
g = @(x) ceil(5*log(x+1));

x = 0:5;

hold on;
plot(x, f(x), '*');
plot(x, g(x), '*');
```

Another example with trigonometric functions:

[image: Octave 2]

wich code is:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

f = @(x) ceil(99*sin(x) + 100*x);
g = @(x) ceil(100*x);

x = 0:10;

hold on;
plot(x, f(x), '*');
plot(x, g(x), '*');
```

Comment: functions are over positive integers.

Comment: You can run a Python/Matlab/Octave code with those two functions and integers only it will also work. I show you continuous functions because they are easier to draw but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @xyz I've done it for you (see update)

Comment: x+sin(x) , you say that rounding will result in x or x+1 ; ok ; so 100 x + 10 sin(x)  for first function, and 100 x for the other one.

Comment: That's a good idea @Lourrran, I'll add this to my answer (-: